# Pro.find is not a function error in mongoose model exports

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my server.js where I can run the code to initialize my server through localhost:7000. And the route that I am running is product.js:

**Product Route:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Pro = require('../model/Product');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Pro.find()
    .sort({ entrydate: -1 })
    .then(product => res.json(product));
});
router.post('/product', ( req, res ) => {
    res.send('Posting a response')
});
module.exports = router;
```

Which gets the error:

> TypeError: Product.route is not a function

**Product Model:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
  // Objects and Properties are here
});

const Product = mongoose.model('products', ProductSchema);
module.exports = { Product };
```

How do I get out of this mess?

Comment: How are you exporting your `Pro` model can we see the code for that please? (just edit your answer to include it)

Comment: Product.route ?? Can you clarify on this. Also are you using mongoose? If yes please share the schema and try to use mongoose.model("name of the model") instead of requiring whole file.

Comment: @1010101  This is my model                                                                                     const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ProductSchema = new Schema({ //Objects and Properties are here})
const Product = mongoose.model('products', ProductSchema);
module.exports = { Product };

Answer (score 4):

You're exporting `Product` within an object:

```
module.exports = { Product };
```

Therefore, what you're doing when you try to find a product is:

```
{ Product }.find();
```

Which is probably what you don't want. Instead:

```
module.exports = Product;
```

or instead of creating a `Product` variable:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('products', ProductSchema);
```

Both should export `products` model only and fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Learn about destructuring in javascript.
You can handle this by

`const {Product} = require('../model/Product'); //recommended`

or

`const any_variable_name = require('../model/Product').Product;`

`module.exports = variable_name` will also help but if you have multiple variables to export then you have to write this whole line multiple times. whereas `module.exports = {v1,v2,v3...vn}` will be more readable

Answer (score 0):

use `module.exports = Product` in your Product Route